# how to add object in properties

Tags: javascript, object

Data is from array of objects result. and is pushed to the `ratings`. I wanted to add another property in my object so the output in console of the code below is:

`ratings` is initialized:

```
ratings = {};

for (var reviewee in result){
     var objReviewee=result[reviewee];

     var revieweeForStarsClass = reviewee;  
     revieweeForStarsClass = revieweeForStarsClass.replace(/\s/g,'');  
     ratings[revieweeForStarsClass]=objReviewee.avgrating;
}
```

So the miguelsobong is the key and I wanted to add another property below it how do i do that?
So it will become

```
testtest1 :{avgrating:4,status:0}
```

Comment: Could you please edit your post and add a minimal, verifiable example.

Comment: sorry. i updated the question.

Comment: Looks like you need to use `Array.prototype.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to give value to ratings.

Comment: hi. whats the syntax of that? can i have an example?

Comment: In your case you can use it like `ratings[revieweeForStarsClass] = Object.assign({},{avgrating:objReviewee.avgrating, status:0}) `

Answer (score 0):

If I have got your problem correctly you could use `Array.prototype.map` like below:

```js
let arr = [{
  miguelsobong: 4.5,
  testtest1: 4
}, {
  miguelsobong: 5.5,
  testtest1: 5
}];
let res = arr.map((o) => {
  let tmp = o.testtest1;
  o.testtest1 = {};
  o.testtest1.avgrating = 4;
  o.testtest1.status = 0;
  return o;
});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: hi sir. is there any other simple way sir?